# Best way to strip everything from a string in javascript but letters and numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to replace everything in a string which is NOT a letter or number

For example:

```
str1='hello! its a beautiful day today12 21 '
```

My desired output is `"helloitsabeautifuldaytoday1221"`

I understand there would be many ways of doing this  but I only looking for something small and efficient possibly little flexible

Comment: [*String.prototype.replace*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.replace) with a regular expression seems appropriate. What have you tried? What are your criteria for "best"?

Comment: `String str1 = '...'` This does not seem JavaScript

Comment: Try https://www.google.com?q=javascript+replace+string.